# IF formula incorporating sequential answers

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to write an IF-THEN formula that outputs sequential numbers (See the example at the bottom). If you need further clarification on the process, just let me know. Here is what I am trying to do:

- I have 4 different programs types (will always be 1 of the 4 - PFP 1 , IRC 2 , Redemption 3 , Consumer Promo 4 in (numbers are assigned in Lump Sum and will always be the same)
- I need column D (Lump Sum Order) to have a formula that looks to see all the programs in the same timing and have it look at the numbers in Column D and count them starting at 1. Each Lump Sum Order  has to start with 1 in each month. So if during the month only 3 programs execute (like December) Lump Sum formula will be assigned IRC - 2 Redemption - 3, Consumer Promo 4. For lump sum order it has to start for each time period with 1. So then in December... IRC will become 1, Redemption will become 2 and Consumer promo will become 3 since PFP was not a program that executed during December.

Example:

**Formula for D1** -Find all the same timing in Column A (A:7-A:9) and the numbers that correlate in Column C  (C:7-C:9)  after analyzing those 2 columns. D:7 would become 1 (because there is no 
PFP - 1), D:8 would be come 2, and D:9 would become 3.

**Lump Sum D1** - I need it to compare Program Timing and Lump Sum and then if it has all 4 programs the Lump Sum Order will be 1,2,3,4, but if it only has 2,3,4 (like December) I need it to start from 1. So 2=1, 3=2, 4=3.

```
Row     Column A         Column B          Column C    Column D
1       Program Timing   Program Type      Lump Sum    Lump Sum Order
2       November         PFP               1           1
3       November         IRC               2           2
4       November         Redemption        3           3
5       November         Consumer Promo    4           4
6       December         IRC               2           1
7       December         Redemption        3           2
8       December         Consumer Promo    4           3
9       January          PFP               1           1
10      January          PFP               1           1
11      January          PFP               1           1
12      January          PFP               1           1
13      January          Consumer Promo    4           2
```

Comment: I’ve made an attempt to clean up your question. Check it and fix it if I got it wrong. I think it’s still hard to understand, so try to fix it (improve it) in any case. P.S. You don’t know where to begin? Press (F1) and search for “formulas”.

Comment: I agree with @G-Man your question is near impossible to understand.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried to make it make sense, but I am not sure that I can via blog. I am going to ask IT if they can either write code for me or I can explain it to them over the phone. Sorry for the confusion. And let me know if it makes more sense.

Comment: Yes, it’s a little clearer; thanks for working on it. But: is my answer right? If it is, please “accept” it by clicking on the check mark ([What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)), and you shouldn’t need to “ask IT if they can either write code for” you. If my answer isn’t right, please show an example of a situation where it yields wrong results (and state what you want the results to be for that input).

Answer (score 1):

Could it be as simple as

- `D2` = `1`
- `D3` = `=IF(A2<>A3, 1, IF(C2=C3, D2, D2+1))`

(and drag down)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't think that will work because not each month will be the same. Some months might only have a 4 because only Consumer Promo executed and that would have to become a 1 since the other 3 program types didn't execute. I know its confusing!

Comment: _Some months might only have a 4 because only Consumer Promo executed and that would have to become a 1 since the other 3 program types didn't execute._ I think that if you add a row 14 to the bottom of your chart containing February | Consumer Pro | 4 and then pull G-Man's formula down you'll see that it does put a 1 in column D